# VS2015 stops responding when I create or open a xamarin forms project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

It has been just two days, I have installed VS2015 and Xamarin comes packed with it. 
All the SDK requirements have been met.
Every thing was working fine but suddenly I was unable to open my project, Android and Windows UWP project keeps on loading  forever and VS doesn't responds to anything.

[image: Explained in this image]

I have tried repairing Xamarin but it didn't work.

I tried creating a new xamarin forms project, in this case VS hangs at "Creating solution image"

Comment: how about creating separate projects for Android and iOS do they work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known issue in the latest Xamarin release (cycle 9), there is a custom build available that may fix this. The bug in question is here https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=52695 and here is the link to the custom build:

http://xvs.xamarin.com/patcheddrops/Xamarin.VisualStudio_4.3.0.785.msi