# Visual Studio 2015 & Xamarin - Can't create new Cross-Platform Project since last update

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I have Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise. I used to be able to click New Project > Templates > Visual C# > Cross-Platform > Blank XAML App (Xamarin.forms Portable).

Now I see Templates > Visual C# > Cross-Platform > Cross Platform App.  When I click on this, it takes me to a new screen where I can select Master Detail or Blank App as well as Forms/Native or Shared/PCL.  I click the Blank App and select Forms & PCL then click Agree.

Visual Studio acts like it is trying to create the project. I get the "Creating project 'appname'...." dialog. However it just sits on this dialog and does nothing else. When I look at the folder structure, I can see that it has created the PCL folder and the Android folder. It does not create any other folder and I ultimately have to kill Visual Studio to get out of it as it will just sit there and spin.

I know the new project is supposed to be for VS2017, which I don't have. I'm not sure why I'm seeing the VS2017 new project instead of the VS2015 Cross-Platform project?  Either way, I really need to create a new PCL project. What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: May be a duplicate of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42578164/vs2015-stops-responding-when-i-create-or-open-a-xamarin-forms-project/42582003#42582003

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this issue has been resolved with a new version of Xamarin for Visual Studio 2015 that rolled out today (v4.3.0.784). Xamarin's Cross-Platform "blank app" template is now available as "Cross Platform App (Xamarin.Forms or Native)". Once the template is selected, a dialog appears allowing the choice of Forms/Native and Shared/PCL projects.

[New Visual Studio 2015 Cross-Platform "Blank App" Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/En5ZZ.png)

[Cross-Platform App Template Helper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmIiA.png)

Comment: I marked this as the answer because I believe this is what the issue ultimately was.  I re-tried creating a new cross-platform app today and it works fine. When I check my Xamarin version (via Programs and Features) I see that it is now on the v4.3.0.784.  I still don't have the 3rd "Blank App (XAML" option, but my "Blank App" option works at least.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved by installing the xamarin version from Jan 27th 2017.

[You can follow my SO post to install an older version of xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42437303/2046795)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. Last week, when it initially occurred, I ended up completely UNinstalling Visual Studio 2015, then reinstalling. The normal Xamarin new project templates were back after that. This morning as I started a new project, the Xamarin templates were missing again. Frustrating! Someone over on the Xamarin.com forums reported the same problem, and that they resolved by uninstalling Xamarin from the Control Panel then reinstalling (presumably from the Xamarin web site). This did NOT work for me when I tried it this morning.

@Daniel suggested rolling back to the previous version of Xamarin (v6.1.4 from January 27th). I tried this, but got the error...

"Gtk# version 2.12.22 or greater must be installed."

The install failed. Looks like I'm not able to roll back to the previous version.

@BillReiss suggested a Xamarin patch build for what seems like the same or similar problem (documented in [VS2015 stops responding when I create or open a xamarin forms project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42578164/vs2015-stops-responding-when-i-create-or-open-a-xamarin-forms-project/42582003#42582003)).  I tried installing this, but it does NOT restore the missing new project templates.

Anyone know where Visual Studio new project templates are stored, and whether it's possible to get new template files online?